# json load as javascript code and use variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If i load a json file like this in HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="json" src="json.json"></script>
```

The json file looks like this and is from another domain and can't be opened by "$getJson"

```
{"name":"Stop","instance":"Find","quality":"port","vsm":"port1","smn":"port2","Protection":"UK","fail":"oun domain","restriction":"other domain"}
```

Is there any way to use the variables from the json file in a JavaScript code?

I've tried this but no luck!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$.getJSON("#id", function(person){
$.each(person, function(key, value)
{document.write(key+"= "+value+"<br />"); 
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: getJSON expects url as its first parameter

Comment: `$.getJSON("#id", function(person)` is not how you get the json.

Comment: You load the URL with `$.getJSON()` (which essentially a shortcut for a GET request typed for a JSON response). Note, however, if the JSON is cross-domain (meaning coming from another site), you have to use [`jsonp`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp) ([more explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2067584/451969)).

Comment: And you can only use JSONP if the server supplying it can pass it to you in that format.

Comment: i cant is wel protectet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `getJSON` wrong way. [Check the official docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), `getJSON` expects URL.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.getJSON('json.json', function(person) {
        $.each(person, function(key, value) {
            document.write(key + '= ' + value + '<br />');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: yes i know this but the json is on another domain, and is protected from being opened like this!

Comment: You'll have to use `jsonp` in that case.